# How to select only center image of iCarousel?

Tags: objective-c, ios, icarousel

I have a iCarousel gallery in which I am getting images from web service. The gallery showing perfectly. I used iCarasouel delegate method "didSelectItemAtIndex" for selecting the First to last image. My icarousel  type is "carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow;".

I selected the image and i got proper index of image, didSelectItemAtIndex works properly only when I scroll gallery and image is moved from center, but when the view is load "Frist or any images" are showing in center are not selected by didSelectItemAtIndex. when I scroll the gallery again and center image is moved from the center then its works fine, then I am able to select the image and go to the next Class or view.

I want to select image which are showing in the center of Icaraosel. Don't know how to do it?

Any hints from experts would be very welcome.

Comment: removed xcode tag as it is only an IDE. also replaced ipad&iphone by icarousel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current index of the image in the given below delegate method

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated:(iCarousel *)carousel1
```

Once your images load s completely then call

```
[self carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated:carousel];
```

Here is the code :

In your viewDidLoad call the method as shown below,here carsousel is in an instance of iCarsouel.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated:carousel];
}


  - (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated:(iCarousel *)carousel1
{
   self.currentItem=carousel1.currentItemIndex;
   NSLog(@"currentItem update== %i",self.currentItem);
}
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: Hello Aman, I want to know that how to use this method as I am working first time on iCaraousel, I don't know much. in carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated() what to do?

Comment: what is currentItem? It says Property not found.

Comment: currentItem is my variable, you can take your in .h file

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if I understood you right: you want to get a `didSelectItemAtIndex:` message right after the initial reload of the view and without scrolling?

just ask for `currentItemIndex` and if you want the selected to be center always call `centerItemWhenSelected`

so just call [self didSelectItemAtIndex:carousel.currentItemIndex];` manually

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (index == carousel.currentItemIndex)
    {
        ///Selected centered item only
    }

}
```